# PHP zerofill number without losing decimals

Tags: php, printf, number-formatting

how can I zerofill a number without loosing decimals?
I tried using sprintf but it deleted all my decimals, what I don't want.

I have the number 12.2 and I want it to look like 012.2, but sprintf gives me 012 and removes the decimals. The function I'm using is: `sprintf('%02u', $number);`

Comment: What do you think does `u` mean? Hmm I guess `signed`; NO, it means `unsigned` and then you still want to ask why you don't see decimals ? And from the manual: `u - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as an unsigned decimal number.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good explanation of the `sprintf` format in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), which applies to `printf` as well.

```
printf('%05.1f', 12.2);
```

Output:

```
012.2
```

Comment: so can I just use $new = sprintf('%05.1f', $old);?

Comment: So I just found out that using this function, 0.1 returns 00.1 but 30.1 returns 030.1, but I want them to always have two digits. How is that possible?